# Problem with "MY PATCH, MY FILE AND NEWNAME"

Tags: excel, vba

> Hello guys, I have this code and the code works perfectly, but when the code runs on another computer it throws the error "Name MyPath & MyFile As MyPath & NewName", now I'm wondering why this happens, is there a better solution or?

```
Sub Zamjena_Imena()
    MyPath = "G:\00 - MIP_AUTO_EXPORT"
    MyFile = "mata.xml"
    NewName = Range("F1")
    Name MyPath & MyFile As MyPath & NewName
    Sheets("BAZA_MIP").Select
    Range("F1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this is because the file path will be different on another computer.

Comment: I changed the path of the file, that's not the case

Comment: You miss a backslash between `MyPath` and `MyFile` when concatenating the strings in the `Name` command

Comment: I don't understand, like this?

Comment: Name MyPath\ & MyFile As MyPath & NewName or?

Comment: This makes no sense to me

Comment: Either you define `"G:\00 - MIP_AUTO_EXPORT\"` or you write `Name MyPath & "\" & MyFile As MyPath & "\" & NewName`

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but it's not working for me again

https://prnt.sc/cHASjcrpO5YN

Comment: "G:\00 - MIP_AUTO_EXPORT\"
this doesn't work either

Comment: Is the G drive mapped on the other (failing) computer exactly as the original? Is it using the same credentials to access the G drive?

Comment: Also, you should qualify `Range("F1")` with a sheet reference - i.e. `Worksheets("sheetname").Range("F1")` = otherwise Excel has to guess which sheet you're referring to.

Comment: The path on the other computer is F:\00 - MIP_AUTO_EXPORT\ , and on mine it is G:\00 - MIP_AUTO_EXPORT\ tkd I don't see the reason. It used to work for me, now it doesn't
It works a little, it doesn't work a little, and I never know why

Comment: https://prnt.sc/C6t0mW4s76AV

Comment: What sheetname is `NewName = Range("F1")` referring to?

Comment: The sheet name is "CODE" in column F1

Comment: As no one has access to you file system or your sheet, no one really can tell why the name command fails. Use the debugger to check the content of the variables and if the path is available on the computer where the code fails. If it exists, check if the user has the privilege to rename the file or if the file is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
Sub Zamjena_Imena()
    MyPath = "G:\00 - MIP_AUTO_EXPORT"
    MyFile = "mata.xml"
    NewName = Worksheets("CODE").Range("F1").Value
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    Debug.Print "Attempting to rename: [" & MyPath & MyFile & "]"
    Debug.Print "to : [" & MyPath & NewName & "]"
    Name MyPath & MyFile As MyPath & NewName
    Sheets("BAZA_MIP").Activate
    Sheets("BAZA_MIP").Range("F1").Select
End Sub
```

Ranges are now qualified, removing the ambiguity.

The above will, if failing, at least tell you (by viewing the immediate window) what it is trying to do.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/9lTmMlu3fQkI
He created "mata", but did not replace it, as it should

Comment: how many problems around a small code

Comment: What does your immediate window tell you?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Fs587faDVq0I

Comment: Obviously missing the backslash again...

Comment: Filip, if you look at the immediate window, you should be able to see what's going wrong. I've added a line to the code which should solve that issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check if it works and let you know

Comment: Thank you, now everything works as it should, one more thing
I have a problem when this code works, it turns off my keyboard where the numbers are, I don't know why but it happens every time

Comment: That's an entirely different question and there's nothing in CLR's answer to change anything of numpad. Are you using a certain hotkey to activate the code?

Comment: If the button is understood as a button then I use it, if not then I don't use it